# How do I automate when an object doesn't have any unique identity on that page?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, identifier

I am automating a pathetically developed web page. One object doesn't have any unique identity. Only option is its `LinkText` name which unfortunately have multiple objects with that same very name. Could you guys please suggest to me me something?

```
<a title="Directory" href="javascript:;" style="color: rgb(95, 96, 98);">People</a>
```

This is that object's inspected element description.

Do use your magic wand if required. Am counting on you all Einsteins!

Comment: do this object has any *unchanged* part? or unchanged parent? could you please post your html code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you consider using XPath it might help, something like this:
        //a[@title='Directory'] [.='People']